# Default value for parameter of Function type in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider a function in Dart file

```
void myFunction({int input = 1, Function(int, String) callback}) {
// ...
}
```

So, I wonder is it possible at all to specify a default value for the `callback` parameter, for instance it can be something like `(_, _) => { }`.

P.S. I know it has `null` as default value and `??` can help to avoid `NPE`, I'm just curious is it possible at all. Cheers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
dynamic func(int i, String s) {
  print(i.toString() + s);
}

void myFunction({int input = 1, Function(int, String) callback = func}) {
  callback(input, " .");
}

void main() {
  myFunction(input: 2);
}
```

Comment: Ah right, I hoped it will be as flexible as in Kotlin, but seems there's no way to have it inline at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: I've got `The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.`

Comment: If the default function does not use any method or class variable, you can set the function  to static. It should be constant then.

Answer (score 4):

The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.

This is what the documents said

This thing can be bypassed like this:

```
 dynamic myCallback(int a,String b) {
      
  }
  
 void myFunction({int input = 1, Function(int, String) callback }) {
    if (callback == null) callback = myCallback;
  }
```

*Edit:*

Alternatively, you can use **anonymous function** with out  `myCallback` function like this:

```
void myFunction({int input = 1, Function(int, String) callback }) {
   if (callback == null) callback = (a,b){};
  }
```